# The Fourier transform $f(x) := x^k \cdot \chi_{[0,1]}(x)$

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

> Find the Fourier transform of the function $f(x) := x^k \cdot \chi_{[0,1]}(x)$, where $k = 1,2,3,\ldots$.

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
\widehat{f}(\omega)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}x^ke^{-i \omega x} dx\\
\end{align*}

According to Wolfram Alpha $\int_{0}^{1}x^ke^{-i \omega x} dx=(i\omega)^{-k-1}\Gamma(k+1)-\Gamma(k+1,i\omega)$, but I do not see how to obtain this. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Why is that $\omega^k$? Shouldn't it be $x^k$?

Comment: Yeah, this is a typo. I will make an edit.

Comment: How does $\omega^k$ inside the integral become $x^k$ outside the integral?

Comment: The integral should be: $$\int_0^1 x^k e^{-i\omega x}\,dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^k\xi_{[0,1]}(x)$.  The Fourier transform $F(\omega)$ of $f(x)$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
F(\omega)&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)  e^{-i\omega x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^1 x^k  e^{-i\omega x}\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{x=t/i\omega}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^{i\omega} \left(\frac{t}{i\omega}\right)^ke^{-t}\,\frac1{i\omega}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} (i\omega)^{-(k+1)}\int_0^{i\omega}t^k e^{-t}\,dt \\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} (i\omega)^{-(k+1)}\left(\int_0^\infty t^k e^{-t}\,dt-\int_{i\omega}^\infty t^k e^{-t}\,dt\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} (i\omega)^{-(k+1)}\left(\Gamma(k+1)-\Gamma(k+1,i\omega)\right)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Your answer is fine, I just had to think it over a bit. Thanks four your help.

Comment: Pleased to hear.  And you're welcome. My pleasure.